# Testing Angular with @angular-redux/store in Storybook

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-redux

I wrote this up on `@angular-redux/store` and was wondering if a solution already existed.

https://github.com/angular-redux/store/issues/551

Here's a recap to save you from reading the link:

Using Angular and Storybook has worked out well so far. However, I have cases where my component is dependent upon @select(). How can I tell the component in my story to use a mocked observable or data point?

Here's my sample code:

```
import { storiesOf, moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

// Modules
... custom modules ...


// Components
...myAppComponents...
import { MyParticularComponent as component } from './my-particular.component';


// Mock Data
... mock json data...

const props = { ...mockData... };

storiesOf('This Particular Component', module)
  .addDecorator(
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [component, ...other components...],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ...custom modules...
      ],
      schemas: [],
      providers: []
    })
  )
  .add('Some View of the Component', () => ({
    component,
    props
  }));
```

And my component has:

```
@Input()
someInput: string;

@select()
stateValue$: Observable<SomeData>;

propOne;
propTwo;

ngOnInit() {
    this.stateValue$.subscribe(data => {
      const { propOne, propTwo } = data;
      this.propOne = propOne;
      this.propTwo = propTwo;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I create props for my component.  If anything has an `@select` decorator, then it needs to belong in an `'@angular-redux::substore::instance::selections'` property.  Here we go:

```
const createProps = {

   const stateValue: DataStruct = {...};

   // Create the Observable.  Need .next and .complete for subscribe.
   const stateValue$: Subject<DataStruct> = MockNgRedux.getSelectorStub('stateValue');
   stateValue$.next(stateValue);
   stateValue$.complete();

   return {
      someInput: 'Hello World!',
      '@angular-redux::substore::instance::selections': {
           stateValue$
       }
   }
}


...
.add('Some View of the Component', () => ({
    component,
    props: createProps()
}));
```